# How to extract content inside html tag attr with python?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I am running a scrapy project. I need to extract a content within a tag attribute like this:

```
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2018-07-08">
```

In this case would be the date within the content attribute. So far I was only able to extract content in the midle of tags.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out ->

```
response.css("time::attr(title)").extract()
```

Reference ->

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/07/web-scraping-in-python-using-scrapy/

**EDIT**

In your case code should be ->

```
response.css("meta::attr(content)").extract()
```

Thanks

Comment: It worked!

response.css("[itemprop=datePublished]::attr(content)").extract()

Comment: Congratulation :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is XPath way:

```
content = response.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="datePublished"]/@content').extract_first()
```